# How to get the number of elements with a non-empty class name

Tags: javascript, html

Sample code:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("p[class]").length);
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

What I get: `4`
What I expect: `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array from the collection, and `filter` by whether its `className` is digital:

```js
const psWithClass = document.querySelectorAll("p[class]");
const countPsWithNumericClass = [...psWithClass]
  .filter(({ className }) => /^\d+$/.test(className))
  .length;
console.log(countPsWithNumericClass );
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

You could also use `reduce` to avoid creating another intermediate array, which would be a bit more efficient, though a bit weirder to read:

```js
const psWithClass = document.querySelectorAll("p[class]");
const countPsWithNumericClass = [...psWithClass]
  .reduce(
    (a, { className }) => a + /^\d+$/.test(className),
    0
  );
console.log(countPsWithNumericClass );
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

Or, without any intermediate arrays at all:

```js
const psWithClass = document.querySelectorAll("p[class]");
const countPsWithNumericClass = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  psWithClass,
  (a, { className }) => a + /^\d+$/.test(className),
  0
);
console.log(countPsWithNumericClass );
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

If you only care whether the class name is not an empty string, use `:not([class=''])`:

```js
const psWithNonEmptyClass = document.querySelectorAll("p[class]:not([class=''])");
console.log(psWithNonEmptyClass.length);
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just edited my question title: It doesn't really matter if the class name is numeric or not. I just wonder how I can get the number of elements with a non-empty class name. Sorry I didn't clarify first.

Comment: See edit, use `:not`. Best to make sure your question title accurately reflects what you're looking for when the question is posted

Comment: Looks great! Is it OK to simplify it to `document.querySelectorAll("p:not([class=''])")`?

Comment: That would match `<p>Hello, world!</p>` - but there is no class, so I think you'd want to exclude it? (if that `<p>` was in the HTML, the result would have 3 elements, not 2) The `:not` there specifically excludes *the empty string* as the class name, but does not exclude there being no class at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` like the following way:

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p')
var count = [...p].filter(el => !isNaN(el.className.trim()) && el.className).length;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can broaden your selector to not select paragraphs that have an empty class attribute.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('p[class]:not([class=""])').length);
```

```html
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="5">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="9">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="">Hello, world!</p>
```